# Why can't Ruby find Rake?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rake

I was using the Rails 3 beta gem yesterday but went back to 2.3.8, and, after cleaning the system gems, I was trying to run a simple Rake task and got this:

```
Peleliu:haml jayfallon$ sudo rake install
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:779:in `report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem rake (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)
 from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:214:in `activate'
 from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:1082:in `gem'
 from /usr/bin/rake:18
```

I am not sure if it has to do with my path being borked or not.

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.7

  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [i686-darwin10.0.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-darwin-10
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
     - /Users/jayfallon/.gem/ruby/1.8
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - :sources => ["http://gems.rubyforge.org/", "http://gems.github.com", "http://gems.github.com", "http://gems.github.com", "http://gems.github.com", "http://gems.github.com", "http://gems.github.com", "http://gems.github.com", "http://gems.github.com", "http://gems.github.com", "http://gemcutter.org/"]
  - REMOTE SOURCES:

     - http://gemcutter.org/
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like rake is trying to run from `/usr/bin/rake`, the system version of Ruby, while you have a custom install of Ruby in `/usr/local`.

1. Make sure you have the rake gem installed for the Ruby installation you're using
2. Make sure the `rake` command is in a directory on your $PATH.

`which gem` should return the rubygems install from `/usr/local/bin`. If not, that's the first problem to solve. Then you want to make sure you have the rake gem in your `/usr/local` Ruby installation:

```
gem list | grep rake
```

should tell you if the gem is installed. If not, run `gem install rake`.

At this point, `which rake` should point to something in your `/usr/local` path. If it doesn't use `find /usr/local | grep rake` to figure out where your Ruby install is keeping gem executables and add that directory to your loadpath.

As a side note, if you're using your own install of Ruby, you might find [rvm](https://rvm.io/) or [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) helpful for managing installs and gems.

Answer (score 0):

You just need add rake on your Gemfile

```
gem 'rake'
```

Comment: I was trying to use Rake outside of a Rails app and just install the latest Haml gem. 

- thanks

Comment: where would that gem file be located at?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and "[A Tale of Abort Traps (or Always Question Your Assumptions)](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/08/24/a-tale-of-abort-traps-or-always-question-your-assumptions/)" helped.